# Can I use unpaired t-test to test the difference between the means of two categories extracted from different questionnaires?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean, proportion

I have 40 questionnaires, each one consists of one question comparing two variables A and B. A and B in these 40 questionnaires are different forms of two categories X and Y.

```
      X       Y
Q1   41      24
Q2   30      15
...
Q40  33      17
```

Each questionnaire was answered by different numbers of subjects. So, since the numbers of subject in each questionnaire vary, I changed the data to the proportions of subjects who either chose A or B:

```
      X       Y
Q1   .63     .37
Q2   .67     .33
...
Q40  .66     .34
```

I want to know if there is a significant difference between X and Y in the whole questionnaires ($H_0: \mu_X=\mu_Y$, $H_a:\mu_X>\mu_Y$). Can I use the independent t-test to do that? If not, what do you suggest? Note that I want to compare the means of X and Y in the whole 40 questionnaires. All conditions to use **the independent t-test** (normality and equal variance) are satisfied.

Comment: If you do not have your answer yet, could you please clarify the data you are collecting. Is my understanding correct: for Q1, 41 subjects answered X et 24 answered Y?

Comment: @Pitouille Yes. It's correct.

Comment: When you say that "you want to compare"... basically you want to check whether or not the results are consistent across the different questionnaire results?

Comment: @Pitouille I want to know if there is a significant difference between the mean of X and Y in the 40 questions (between the mean of X in 40 questions and the mean of Y in 40 questions).

Comment: Sorry for the many questions... I am still trying to understand your experiment! If the questionnaires consist of the same question, what is specific to your experiment that requires to treat them independently? Are you comparing different populations through each instance of the questionnaire?

Comment: @Pitouille No problem. Thanks for your help. The experiment is supposed to compare the means of regular and irregular verbs. Each  question compares a specific verb (like come vs. came), but the whole 40 questions compares regulars vs. irregulars. The categories that we are comparing are regulars and irregulars. The main issue here is that the numbers of subjects who answered each question is different. And if I use proportion of subjects in each question, as mentioned by BruceET it turns my categories to dependent variables.

Comment: I think you should update your question with this information. People do not always read comments and, besides that, it will reposition your question on the top of the list. I have the feeling that you are looking for a test to compare multiple proportions. The thing that I did not get is whether you expect to see the same "trend" across questions, i.e. proportion of X in Q1 is similar to proportion in Qn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130320/discussion-between-aryasinic-and-pitouille).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your experiment and your manipulation of data so far,
then in your second table you have two fractions for each questionnaire that add to 1.00 (as for Q2: 0.67 + 0.33 = 1.00).

In that case you may *not* treat the two columns X and Y (each with 60 fractions) as independent variables for a two sample t test (pooled or Welch). Once you know the proportion in X, the proportion in Y is
determined and so provides no additional information.

So it makes sense to focus just on the X column.
From the fragment shown, it seems that the X proportions tend to be
greater than the Y proportions, and the crux of your question is
whether X's do tend to be above 0.50. Now, let binomial random variable $G$ be the the number of X's (out of 60) that exceed 0.50.

Because I don't have the whole of the second table, I can't find $G$
for your experiment. But let me show results if $G = 45.$

In R, we use the exact binomial test `binom.test` as follows:

```
binom.test(45, 60, 1/2, alt="gr")

        Exact binomial test

data:  45 and 60
number of successes = 45, number of trials = 60, 
 p-value = 6.726e-05
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6414602 1.0000000
sample estimates:
 probability of success 
                   0.75
```

It turns out that any $G \ge 37$ is enough larger than 30
to give a P-value below $0.05 = 5\%,$ and hence a significantly
larger proportions in column X at the 5% level.

```
binom.test(37, 60, 1/2, alt="gr")$p.val
[1] 0.04623049
```

The figure below shows the binomial distribution of $G.$ One rejects the null hypothesis that X and Y
are equal against the alternative that X proportions are larger
for $G \ge 37.$

[image]

R code for figure:

```
x = 0:60;  PDF = dbinom(x, 60, .5)
hdr="PDF of BINOM(60,.5)"
plot(x, PDF, xlab="G", type="h", lwd=2, main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=36.5, lwd=2, lty="dotted", col="red")
```

Comment: Is there any way to transform the data in a way that fits the independent t-test.? How can I normalize the variation of the numbers of subjects who answered each question? Or can I use the paired t-test?

Comment: Paired t test might be OK if Y-X differences normal. Binomial test avoids some difficulties. What does binomial test give for your actual  data?

Comment: Since the numbers of subjects in each question is different, it's important to compare means of proportions of X and Y in the whole questions. If you could edit your answer to include Paired t-test, I could check your answer as a solution.

Comment: Syntax in R would be `t.test(X, Y, pair=T)` or `t.test(X-Y)`.